# How to get offset from audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

I need to insert another audio on specific offset (where space existed in audio track).

So, For that, i need to fetch offset of each space from audio and then apply some ffmpeg/sox command to insert another aduio on that offset.

Please share me some command to fetch the offset for space
first so, later, i could mix the another audio on same offset.

Please suggest your view/command or any library.

I think, it would be possible in FFMPEG OR SOX.

Updated:
I have two audio files.
In which one audio files contains some songs but, there are some space at some interval. These space should be fill by another audio.

example:
Audio 1 - song - audio has space at 5 places.

audio 2 - a people name audio.

output - audio one should fill up the all 5 places by aduio 2.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain more clearly. From your question I'm guessing you want to merge two audio tracks, but this should occur at a specific time or times. What is the desired result for the merging? Assuming two stereo inputs you can have a four channel output or a two channel (stereo) output.

Comment: Please find updated question.